# How to sort list containing lists, with 2 refs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list like this
`[[2, 1], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 5], [1, 4]]`

So i want to sort this list according to 1st element, but if 1st element of 2 items are equal then sort according to 2nd element and i want to do it in reverse order(decreasing order)

i used this

`arr.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)`

but its result is 
`[[2, 1], [2, 5], [1, 2], [1, 4], [0, 3]]`

I want result something like this

`[[2, 5], [2, 1], [1, 4], [1, 2], [0, 3]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like so :

```
a = [[2, 1], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 5], [1, 4]]

a.sort(key= lambda x:x[0])
a.reverse()

print(a)
```

`reverse=True` on `.sort()` reverse the list but the items with same value are not sorted.

or simpler

```
a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: `reverse=True on .sort() reverse the list but the items with same value are sorted in ascending order` <--  that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
ls = [[2, 1], [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 5], [1, 4]]
ls_sorted = sorted(ls, key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]), reverse=True)
print(ls_sorted)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 5], [2, 1], [1, 4], [1, 2], [0, 3]]
```